# I just got a Mac! How do I do "end" , "home", "page up" and "page down" in my terminal/VIM editor?

Tags: macos, unix, vim, terminal, keyboard-layout

I write a lot of python in my VIM, on the terminal.
What do I do?

Comment: actually, if you need to ask these question, you should really consider using another editor or IDE to write python. For the matter, home => ^, end => $, page up = ^f, page down = ^b; note that you need to quit edit mode using Esc first, and then go in again by e.g. i or a....

Comment: @bubu bah! I say. I do all my coding in VIM, it is an excellent editor, even for python.

Comment: Are you referring to the 'home' 'end' 'page up' 'page down' keys on your keyboard, or are you simply looking for the proper VIM navigation commands?

Answer (score 17):

Do the standard over-30-year-old vi shortcuts of

`^f` (forward == page down)
`^b` (back == page up)
`^` (that's a shift-6 caret for start of line) and
`$` (end of line)

...not work?

Or are you looking for PC-style keyboard keys for those functions?  For those, use Fn + arrow keys:

Fn + down arrow == page down
Fn + up arrow == page up
Fn + left arrow == home
Fn + right arrow == end

Comment: The 'Fn + arrow' key combinations don't work for me using Terminal.App and Vim.

Comment: `|` is equivalent to HOME: they both go to the 0th column of the line, rather than to the first non-space character in it.

Comment: In mc on Lion Fn + arrows only works right for me. ^f, ^b keys loads previous\next file in current folder. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for this! Can I also move the cursor while in insert mode? I can do this on Windows and Linux. Is Mac OS X just as good as them? Minor correction: 0 does first position of current line, whereas ^ does first nonblank character of current line.

Comment: This does not answer the question.  To get HOME and END to work in vim and in the shell, put `bind '"\e[1~":"\eOH"'` and `bind '"\e[4~":"\eOF"'` in your $HOME/.bashrc .

More Mac-friendly and Linux-friendly bash/vim customization at https://github.com/sudoer/dotfiles .

Comment: @AlanPorter You may have misread the Question. The way OP worded it, it's unclear if he just wanted to do those movements, or if he wanted to specifically use those keyboard keys on a PC-style keyboard. Stefan Lasiewski asked for clarification in a comment on the Question, but OP never clarified. Note also that PC101/105-key keyboards are much less common on Macs. MacBooks [Air|Pro] and Apple's standard desktop keyboard (which is the Bluetooth one) don't have those keys. This makes the "he doesn't have those keys and just wants to do those movements" interpretation more likely than not.

Comment: Fair enough.  This answer originally struck me as a Steve Jobs style "you're holding it wrong" answer.  But now I see how the question could be interpreted multiple ways.  I hope the guy gets his vim and Mac working together.

Answer (score 7):

Vim commands (these aren't mac specific):

end of line: **$**

start of line: **0**

page down: **ctrl+f**

page up: **ctrl+b**

Answer (score 2):

If you look in the terminal keyboard settings - you can swap the actions for page up/down and shift page up/down. That works in default vim and like you'd expect on remote boxes.

gg and G are all you need for home/end. (I did spend a while trying to make it work)

Answer (score 1):

To get HOME and END to work in vim and in the shell, put `bind '"\e[1~":"\eOH"'` and `bind '"\e[4~":"\eOF"'` in your $HOME/.bashrc file.

More Mac-friendly and Linux-friendly bash/vim customization at https://github.com/sudoer/dotfiles .  In the bash scripts, look for the words $OSTYPE and "darwin".  There's a similar "Darwin" block in the vimrc for Mac-specific vim tweaks.