# home/end in INSERT mode in vi on a Mac

Tags: macos, mac, vim, terminal, vi

On a Mac I can go to the start and end of an line in vi, when not in INSERT mode:

`^` (start of line)
`$` (end of line)

This is for example explained here:
[**How do I do “end” , “home”, “page up” and “page down” in my terminal/VIM editor?**](https://superuser.com/questions/156115/i-just-got-a-mac-how-do-i-do-end-home-page-up-and-page-down-in-my-te)

But how do I go to the beginning and end of an line in vi, when in INSERT mode?

<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> scrolls between windows
<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> goes backwards one word
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> does nothing
<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> goes backwards/forwards one word
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> goes backwards/forwards one word
<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> goes to the beginning/end of the terminal buffer

Summary of solution provided by @romainl below:
Terminal > Preferences > Settings > Keyboard > +
Key: Home, Modifier: None, Action: Send Text, \017^
Key: End, Modifier: None, Action: Send Text, \017$

I found this very neat solution, which saves a key stroke:  [**Move to the beginning of line while in Insert mode**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545078/move-to-the-beginning-of-line-while-in-insert-mode).

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> followed by <kbd>0</kbd> (home) or <kbd>$</kbd> (end) or <kbd>^</kbd> (first non-white-space character)

And here is a very elaborate answer:  [**Traversing text in Insert mode**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737163/traversing-text-in-insert-mode)

Comment: Your person view points does not really add anything of value to the question.  Can you remove this commentary and focus on what your question is exactly?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**First,** you are not supposed to move the cursor around when in insert mode.

**Second,** only *some* Mac keyboards come without `<Home>`/`<End>` keys. You should have taken a closer look before shelling out all that cash for a computer that's so painful to use.

**Third,** you can use the following shortcuts when you don't have physical `<Home>`/`<End>` keys:

- <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> for `<Home>`
- <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> for `<End>`

**Fourth,** Terminal.app captures `<Home>`/`<End>` anyway so you'll have to edit those bindings in the "preferences" window if you want Vim to receive `<Home>` and `<End>`.

For `<Home>`, press `Ctrl+o` (it inserts `\017`) then `^`:

[image: Home]

For `<End>`, press `Ctrl+o` (it inserts `\017`) then `$`:

[image: End]

Comment: 0) Thanks. Worked. You are genius. 1) I can on Linux and Windows, so I want to be able to on Mac. 2) Wanted Unix based OS and work only supports Ubuntu, which I like much less than Mint, which I run on my PC at home. 3) Thanks. Doesn't work in INSERT mode. 4) Thanks for the solution. I have added a short summary of your solution to my question. Thanks!

Comment: I just have to be careful not pressing the home key, when on the terminal command line, because the written command is executed, if I press home or end; i.e. after applying your fix.

Comment: You could set iterm up so that it sends a very special sequence and map that sequence in Vim.

Comment: I will try that. If I do \033[F for End and \033[H for Home, then Home and End works in the terminal, but not in Vim.

Answer (score 1):

The system gvimrc file distributed with MacVim has two sets of mappings.  One is enabled by default, the other disabled.  Curiously, neither contains a command to go to the start/end of the line in Insert mode, but it is still worth taking a look:

```
:e $VIM/gvimrc
```

You could add something to your vimrc file like this:

```
inoremap <D-Left> <Home>
inoremap <D-Right> <End>
```

A little test shows that this works in the GUI but not the terminal, so maybe that should go in your gvimrc file.  How about

```
inoremap <C-V><S-Left> <Home>
inoremap <C-V><S-Right> <End>
```

Where you do NOT type those commands literally:  `<C-V>` is one character and `<S-Left>` is another.  On my machine, using Mac's Terminal.app, I get the same effect with this, typed literally:

```
inoremap <Esc>OC <End>
inoremap <Esc>OD <Home>
```

When using the GUI, this may get overwritten by the settings in the system gvimrc file.